# Remove header from delimited text file

Tags: powershell, text, csv

I have text files in which data is delimited by a forward slash. It's easy enough to import and feed it into a custom object, but the files have headers that include the delimiter. Example below:

```
HEADER LINE 1/INFO/MOREINFO
HEADER LINE 2/INFO/MOREINFO
HEADER LINE 3/INFO/MOREINFO
HEADER LINE 4/INFO/MOREINFO
HEADER LINE 5/INFO/MOREINFO
HEADER LINE 6/INFO/MOREINFO
HEADER LINE 7/INFO/MOREINFO

LINE1A/1B///1E/1F/1G/1H
LINE2A/2B/2C//2E//2G/2H
...
/END/
```

The lines "LINE1A", "LINE1B", etc. have the data I need to import. Using `-split '/'` lets me split everything into a nice array, but only if that header's not there.

```
$data = (Get-Content text.txt).Replace('Line', '/Line') -split('/')
```

If the header is present, the first elements in the `$data` array include the header.

I've tried string manipulation tricks, but unfortunately the header text isn't consistent form one file to the next. The number of lines (always 7) and the number of slashes (2 per header line) is consistent, but the text in each line varies.

Since `Get-Content` produces arrays split be carriage returns (correct me if I'm wrong), I though I could just remove the first 7 array elements. This code works to remove the first element:

```
$data = (Get-Content text.txt) 
$data = $data | Where-Object {$_ -ne $data[0]}
```

But it's not very scalable. I don't want to loop the command 7 times. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe some RegEx based on carriage returns and/or slashes?

Answer (score 4):

Simple stuff here, use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to skip the first 7 lines!

```
$data = (Get-Content text.txt | Select -Skip 7).replace('Line','/Line') -split('/')
```

If there's a blank line on line 8 you may want to skip the first 8 lines instead.

Comment: Might have to deal with that last line as well.

Comment: He said that his process works if he doesn't have the header rows, so I figured it was safe to assume he had something to deal with that last line already.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the file read into the array `$data`, simply copy all but the first 7 lines of data to a new array

```
 $data2 = $data[7..($data.length-1)]
```

and then work with `$data2`.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers and lines cannot be trusted I offer something else. Lets filter out all of the lines starting with header or end and filter empty lines. Then lets create the custom objects just like `Import-CSV` would

```
$fileContents = Get-Content "file"
$csv = $fileContents | Where-Object{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -and $_ -notmatch "^(HEADER|/END/)"}
# Determine the number of headers from the file 'CSV' line
$numberOfHeaders = $csv[0].split("/").Count
ConvertFrom-Csv $csv -Header (1..$numberOfHeaders|ForEach-Object{"LINE $_"}) -Delimiter "/"
```

This works using your sample input data only ignoring the ellipsis. So now you have the equivalent to what a proper CSV would look like if using `IMport-CSV`. The header was me guessing. Would not take much to change that if other needs arise.

```
LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3 LINE 4 LINE 5 LINE 6 LINE 7 LINE 8
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
1A     1B                   1E     1F     1G     1H    
2A     2B     2C            2E            2G     2H
```

If you don't need the leading "LINE" *on the data* then a simple pipe would fix that before the conversion

```
ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "^LINE"}
```

If you want to remove it from the header then play with this `1..$numberOfHeaders|ForEach-Object{"LINE $_"}`. So if you are fine with just numbered columns you could just leave it at `1..$numberOfHeaders`